# Does BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress hold the BackgroundWorker_DoWork thread?

Tags: c#, listbox, backgroundworker

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to trigger a thread, in turn calling a function, which in turn calls Backgroundworker_ProgressChange via .ReportProgress();

Within ProgressChange, I am attempting to write entries to a log file from with some information received via the passed object.

Can I assume that ProgressChange actually holds the BackgroundWorker thread?  Or will I miss some data in my log?

Specifically, I have ProgressChange adding items to a listbox.  Conditionally, if the listbox.items.count > 15, I would like to enumerate the listbox.items and write them to a log file.

I'm flexible with a solution.  It is not mandatory that the listbox not "miss" entries.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik the ProgressChanged actions are Posted, so DoWork does not have to wait. But how would that matter to you writing activities?

The Progress updates will come in sequence, they won't (can't) interrupt each other. Just be careful not to make them too slow.

Comment: Well, writing a file would be the slowest possible operation.  By "ProgressChanged actions are Posted," do you mean they queue?  If so, where (where does it take the memory)?  I couldn't find docs on this.  After reviewing with a developer here (I'm an analyst/systems & network guy), it became clear that relying on the "ProgressChanged queue" to hold whatever data I'm feeding it would create too scary of a growth issue.  I'll just use a single-dimensional array to hold, then flush to the log file every 50 items or so.

Comment: I think several wires are getting crossed here. The Bgw and it's Progress reporting are intended to use with the GUI - updating listboxes etc. You're writing-to-file part could be done inline in the DoWork thread or on another thread with ThreadPool or TPL. But making it thread-safe should be your main concern, not the size of the data.

Comment: I created a struct, then a list of this struct to store the values.  Checking the count of the list, I'll write a file at a given count.  What your response indicates is that I could spawn this "write a file" operation in another thread, but you fear that this will cause some sort of queue in its own right.  Therefore, what _is_ the safest mechanism to avoid this, less writing my own queue handler?  Should I not just keep it simple, stay with one thread executing and holding the file?  (disclaimer: i'm new to programming and just read up on thread safety)

Comment: This is drifting a long way from the original question. Maybe describe what you need in a new question. Try to isolate the problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help Henk.  It seems there are a lot of in-depth threads about thread safety and file open issues.  Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256517/best-programming-approach-methodology-to-assure-thread-safety